# Where do these parasitic capacitances appear?

Tags: dac, parasitic-capacitance

So here:

[image]

I assume each transistor has some sort of parasitic capacitance and that adds up into the non inverting terminal of the op amp? Why do those parasitic capacitances appear and how can i reduce them?

And in this case:

[image]

These capacitances appear because of Q4/Q3... ? They depend on what?

Answer (score 2):

The current-steering DAC has less parasitic capacitance and is generally faster.

In the R-string DAC, whenever a new code is chosen, about N nodes have to charge or discharge when a new code is selected, and these (and the parasitic capacitance associated with the S & D of the FETs there) may have to charge from a relatively high source resistance.

In the current-steering DAC, when a code changes, only the drain of the output FETs needs to change; all other nodes remain at nearly the same voltage. Therefore this DAC is faster. There is parasitic C at the tail of each differential switch, but (when properly designed), the voltage on these nodes doesn't change with different codes, so the is no significant (speed) effect of this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at how these circuits are constructed physically. There are parasitic capacitances on every interconnect wire, of course. For MOSFETs (built on conventional bulk substrates, not SOI) you will have capacitance at every drain and source to the body, capacitance at the gate to the channel/body, and fringing capacitance from the gate to the source and drain.

There is capacitance everywhere in a real circuit. Much of it can not be completely eliminated, so we learn to live with it.